# How to debug server side TypeScript code in WebStorm

Tags: debugging, typescript, webstorm, server-side

Comparing this to Visual Studio Code all you need to do is allow source maps and VSCode will debug TypeScript however I can't achieve the same on WebStorm.

I can easily debug server side JavaScript in WebStorm but not TypeScript

Comment: What WebStorm version do you use? Do you have source maps? Debugging in the Imageboard sample project (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScriptSamples/tree/master/imageboard) works fine for me: I start a Node.js debug session for server.js file and breakpoints that are put in server.ts are hit.

Comment: I am using the latest version "2016.1". I will give that a try. So all you do is compile your ts files and start a new debugging session then WebStorm will automatically pick the ts files breakpoints?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a built-in WebStorm TypeScript compiler to compile the code and generate the source maps. Breakpoints are set in TS file, thanks to the source maps WebStorm can stop on them. If you still have problems with debugging your app, please report an issue with more details on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Comment: @Ekaterina, how would you manage if the generated js files and maps where on a different folder e.g: a dist folder. In VSCode you have an output path setting but I can't find anything similar in Webstorm.

Comment: @robertohuertasm you can either check Use output path and specify the path to the fist folder (simply dist, if it's in the project root) in Preferences | Languages and Frameworks | TypeScript (under Enable TypeScript compiler) or add tsconfig.json file that would describe your project configuration (including the output directory) and point a built-in compiler to it.

Comment: @EkaterinaPrigara in my project I have nested tsconfig.json files. Will Webstorm honor the working directory setting and use the specific tsconfig.json file or will it use the one relative to the root project's folder? I don't know what I'm doing wrong as for some reason js maps are not being used and ts files are not being reached by the debugger. Transpiled js files are.

Comment: @robertohuertasm if you select Use tsconfig.json, the built-in compiler will use tsconfig files the same way the compiler would, if you run it from the command line. Sorry, but I'm not sure we can solve the debugging issue without having a sample project. Please report an issue on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB or contact tech support https://www.jetbrains.com/support/

Comment: @EkaterinaPrigara I've just created the issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23632 with a sample project https://gitlab.com/robertohuertasm/ws-test

Comment: @robertohuertasm thank you! We'll investigate.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone else wrestling with debugging TypeScript in WebStorm/IDEA, I had similar frustrations as OP (possibly for different reason). My issue was simply that I didn't set the working directory to the `dist` folder in the node run configuration. I am running tests in Jest and assumed the working dir should be the root of my project. Set it to `dist` and debugging started working!

Further info...

Source .ts files in `src`

Typescript version: 2.0.3

File `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

Jest config (in `package.json`):

```
  "jest": {
    "scriptPreprocessor": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/dist/preprocessor.js",
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx)$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js"
    ]
  }
```

Run configuration...

Working directory: `<project_root>/dist`

Javascript file: `../node_modules/jest-cli/bin/jest.js`

Application params: `--runInBand`

Hope it helps!

Comment: [edited] It seems to work even in the root directory, what made it work for me was using the 'node' run configuration and not 'npm script'.

Comment: Setting `outDir` in the compiler options did the trick for me.

Answer (score 8):

was trying to find a way to let Webstorm/Intellij to watch the TS file change and restart server in debug mode. Looks like [`ts-node-dev`](https://github.com/wclr/ts-node-dev) which IHMO is faster than `nodemon` in terms of live-reload because it **shares** Typescript compilation process between restarts.

> npm i ts-node-dev --save-dev

Then in your `Run/Debug Configuration`, add a `node.js` config with below params:

`JavaScript file ---> node_modules/ts-node-dev/lib/bin.js`

`Applicationi parameters ---> --respawn -- src/script/local.server.ts`

[image]

Now save the config and run with `Debug`, you should be able to set break point as well as live reload server on any TS code change.

I wrapped up a small library for this if you happen to develop with `aws lambda`

> https://github.com/vcfvct/ts-lambda-local-dev

Comment: I'm a little late to the party. I managed to make debugging "work" with your information. As in, enabling "break at first line" it does break in the index.js. However, I can't get to the breakpoints if I run an EP call from the browser. Any tips?

Comment: @Erythros what do you mean by `EP` call? once you run the debug in webstore, you should be able to set breakpoints in your xxx.ts as long as your source map is configured at tsconfig.json. As it should also do `live reload` on change because ts-node-dev is watching change and recompile and re-spawn.

Answer (score 3):

Just want to add what worked for me with Webstorm 2021.1.1

I found the easiest way is to go to your package.json and right click the green triangle next to the npm script you want to run.  Then select debug.

I am able to apply the breakpoints to my typescript code and it works perfectly. Coming from .Net where it was always pretty straight forward to debug, I am glad to see webstorm making it just as simple.

This is my npm script that I choose to debug.

```
"dev": "env-cmd -f ./config/dev.env concurrently -k -n COMPILER,NODEMON -c gray,blue \"tsc -w\" \"nodemon -w dist dist/index.js\"",
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a specific version of node called `ts-node`.

[image: Using ts-node with Webstorm]

First add in your `package.json` file:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "8.1.0",
    "typescript": "3.2.4"
  },
```

Run `npm install` and the `node_module/.bin/` directory will include the `ts-node` or `ts-node.cmd` required for Windows.

Obviously these versions will move. You may see inside the `package.json` of `ts-node` project which version of typescript they are using to be the closest as possible.

Then you can add breakpoints. The only downside I see is that you must define the Javascript file (which is a ts file) into the configuration, instead of just right-click + run.

If you have the `xyz is not a function` error, check that your `tsconfig.json` file doesn't have `"noEmit": false,`

Answer (score 2):

There is not much needed to debug a Node.js project with TypeScript when using Webstorm/IntelliJ.

You should make sure you have enabled source maps in your `tsconfig.json`:

```json
//tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...,
    "sourceMap": true,
    ...
  }
}
```

Source maps will be needed to allow you to set breakpoints directly in your TypeScript files.

Then you should remember to use Node option `--inspect` or `--inspect-brk`. I would suggest in most cases to use `inspect-brk` since this one is pausing execution once Node is up and running.

You can add simple script to run your TypeScript Node app using eg. ts-node in a `package.json`:

```json
//package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev-debug": "ts-node --inspect-brk src/index.ts" 
  }
}
```

And run that using `pnpm|yarn|npm` package manager:

```bash
#shell
pnpm run dev-debug
```

Then in your shell you will get nice URL like `ws://127.0.0.1:9229/0f2c936f-b1cd-4ac9-aab3-f63b0f33d55e` which you can use to attach to your debugger.

To do that in WebStorm/IntelliJ you can just click on it with keys pressed:

⇧ + ⌘ + Click

Ctrl + Shift + Click

Keys depends on your OS.

After that you will have your debugger up and running in an IDE.

Answer (score 1):

For running WebStorm(2017.2.3) debugger around typescript sources I did:

1. Setup `Node.js` configuration:

   - Working directory: `root/of/the/project` (where located my `package.json`)
   - JavaScript file: `dist/index.js`
2. I am compiling my TypeScript with `gulp-typescript`, but more important the source-map files. So for compiling was used task like below:

   ```
   const gulp = require('gulp');
   const ts = require('gulp-typescript');
   const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
   const merge = require('merge2');

   const tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json', {
     declaration: true,
     typescript: require('typescript'),
   });

   gulp.task('default', () => {
     const result = gulp.src('./app/**/*.ts')
       .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
       .pipe(sourcemaps.identityMap()) // optional
       .pipe(tsProject());

     return merge([
   result.js
         .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', { includeContent: false, sourceRoot: '../app' }))
         .pipe(gulp.dest('dist')),
       result.dts
         .pipe(gulp.dest('dist')),
     ]);
   });
   ```

All source TS files located in './app' folder, all compiled files located in `./dist` folder. Most important source-files option `sourceRoot`, wrong value not bring you to ts file.

By `sourcemaps.write('.', { includeContent: false, sourceRoot: '../app' }` I am writing my `.map` files beside `.js` files and make reference to `app` folder. I no need content in `.map` files because it's already there (`app` folder).

Thanks to @Ekaterina I was able to run Node debug with Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `package.json` with a `build` and `start` scripts:

```
//package.json

{
...
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build && node ./dist/index.js",
    "build": "webpack --config ./webpack.config.js",
...
}
```

In this configuration, all compiled files are located under `dist/`. The entry point is `index.js`.

Make sure your `tsconfig.json` has the `sourceMap` option enabled:

```
//tsconfig.json

{
...
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap": true
    }
...
}
```

In your `webpack.config.js` file, make sure you have the following properties as shown below:

```
//webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development', // This is important!, if you set 'production' it won't let you debug
    devtool: 'source-map',
    ...
}
```

Finally, set up your WebStorm `Run/Debug Configuration` as follows:

```
...
package.json: ~/path/to/your/package.json
Command: run
Scripts: start
...
```

Now add a breakpoint and start debugging