# How to debug typescript in Intellij IDEA

Tags: node.js, typescript

[Image shows my Project Structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoEsX.png)I am writing back-end for order app in typescript with mongoose database.I am using 'intellij-IDEA' IDE for development. Project run with gulp task runner.I am testing my api's with postman.In some cases, I am unable to track the flow of code from project. I have tried printing with 'console.log()'. But, it has limits. So, help me to debug typescript as it doesn't involve any browser activity.

Comment: Add more details. Show structure of your project in Idea. Why you did not tell about Idea, but use it in the title? What do you want to get from idea in this case? What you have tried with idea?

Comment: I am using 'intellij-idea' IDE for development. I want to know how to debug in that IDE. As this project doesn't require browser for running. I am testing API's with POSTMAN application. It is easy to add breakpoint & debug if it was Front-end but how to do it in the case of calling to Back-end API's.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to debug server side TypeScript code in WebStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36661384/how-to-debug-server-side-typescript-code-in-webstorm)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get IntelliJ to debug Node Typescript apps while using `nodemon` as the node interpreter and `ts-node` as the inline transpiler. No need to pre-compile the code, `ts-node` does it real-time in memory.

```
// nodemon.json

{
    "execMap": {
        "js": "node",
        "ts": "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node"
    },
    "watch": [
        "app",
        "config"
    ],
    "ext": "js,ts"
}
```

[image: Run config]

Then run the Node.JS run configuration in Debug mode, and breakpoints are hit!

If using Linux, change the node interpreter to `./node_modules/bin/nodemon` (without .cmd)

Comment: It worked well for some time, but now it just starts my server and doesn't stop on any breakpoint

Comment: ts-node ^5.0.1 changed its settings

Comment: Didn't work for me. wind up getting `node: bad option: --expose_debug_as=v8debug`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [node-instpector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-inspector), it does a good job helping debug NodeJS apps. Here's a good [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03qGA-GJXjI).