# How to debug TypeScript in WebStorm Node.js Remote Debug?

Tags: node.js, debugging, typescript, webstorm

I have a TypeScript Node.js Restify app running inside Docker container. I can connect the WebStorm Node.js Remote Debugger, but I can only debug the compiled JS files and not the TS files.

In the `tsconfig.json` I have `"sourceMap": true` set.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug server side TypeScript code in WebStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36661384/how-to-debug-server-side-typescript-code-in-webstorm)

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution using **ts-node** there are a few steps that you should do for doing it.

First, you must add `"esModuleInterop": true` and `"sourceMap": true` to your tsconfig.json

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "lib": ["es2015"]
}
```

After that, you should install the ts-node package.

```
npm i -D ts-node
```

The last step is adding to edit the Run/Debug Configurations of the WebStorm.

Go to Run/Debug Configurations window.

Add new Node.js configuration using the `+`.

Change the `Node parameters` to `--require ts-node/register`

Then, change the Javascript file to your Typescript file, for me it is: `src/app.ts`

Press the **OK** button.

**Run this configuration as dubug.**

Answer (score 1):

What run confoguration do you use - **Node.js Remote**? Remote debugging with sourcemaps only works if sources are inlined (`inlineSources=true` in **tsconfig.json**)

Comment: I enabled `inlineSources` but the breakpoint in my `.ts` file isn't being hit.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue, @lena answer didn't work for me either, but I solved the problem by adding `"inlineSourceMap": true` to the `compilerOptions` of my tsconfig.json.